How to ignore empty rows when submitting to database
I have a problem when I submit the form which had empty rows so that in the database the empty rows are still inputted even though they are empty which causes the next input to skip the empty row.

You mean something like this?
function submitFR() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OWqOlqy_pfZgmtgOx8i-b-V_u3IBZnsOklahh4pXGSM").getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OonemP29xCjyChjYUYJWWGKyjo-BFFUVSJhoyx6MQEg").getSheetByName("Database Jurnal");

  var rowsToSubmit = [];

  // Loop through rows 22 to 25
  for (var row = 22; row <= 25; row++) {
    var values = [
      formSS.getRange("B" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("D" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("E" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("L" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("M" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("N" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("O" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("P" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("R" + row).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("S" + row).getValue(),
    ];

    // Check if any values are non-empty in the row before adding to the list
    if (values.some(value => value !== "")) {
      rowsToSubmit.push(values); // Add non-empty rows to the array
    }
  }

  // Write the non-empty rows to the datasheet
  if (rowsToSubmit.length > 0) {
    datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowsToSubmit.length, rowsToSubmit[0].length).setValues(rowsToSubmit);
  }
}


Can you help me again Sir? I am having trouble sharing the data entry form with my colleague. It always shows a notification that "Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document.", I have given him access permission, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

I have no idea. I do not share my spreadsheets
